How can I attach more than one auxiliary effect to Android AudioTrack?
I've read all the documentation on attaching aux effects to AudioTrack but can't understand how I can attach more than one effect.
Attaching an effect seems simple enough.
But how does the setAuxEffectSendLevel know which effect to apply the level to as there is no parameter identifying the related effect?
Does it simply refer to the last added effect?
Also how can one of the effects be detached. The documentation says:

To detach the effect from the audio track, call this method with a
null effect id.

But in my code below, by attaching a null effect, which of my effects would be removed?
The code below also has no effect at all on the audio. Why?
PresetReverb reverb = new PresetReverb(1, 0);
reverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
reverb.setEnabled(true);
audioTrack.attachAuxEffect(reverb.getId());
audioTrack.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

BassBoost bb = new BassBoost(0, 0);
bb.setStrength(1000);
bb.setEnabled(true);
audioTrack.attachAuxEffect(bb.Id);
audioTrack.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

//this code detaches which effect?
audioTrack.AttachAuxEffect(0);


Are you using .Net framework for aux effects ?

My app is actually Xamarin Forms, but I'm using the underlying Android renderers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.mediaplayer.attachauxeffect?view=net-android-34.0, so I guess it's .NET for Android

Your code detaches the wrong effect because you use an index (0) that might not correspond to the reverb effect. To fix this, store the effect's ID when attaching it and use that ID for detachment later. This ensures you detach the intended effect.
Can you try after changing these lines:
int reverbId = audioTrack.attachAuxEffect(reverb.getId());  int bbId = audioTrack.attachAuxEffect(bb.getId());  audioTrack.attachAuxEffect(reverbId);  

Thanks Bob, but the return value of attachAuxEffect is void

Also there is no such method as detachAuxEffect, hence the null id parameter in my attachAuxEffect call.

Tracing the C++ source of android I ended up on this line (comments mine):
# media/libaudioclient/AudioTrack.cpp
status_t AudioTrack::attachAuxEffect(int effectId)
{
    AutoMutex lock(mLock);
    status_t status;
    mAudioTrack->attachAuxEffect(effectId, &status);
    if (status == NO_ERROR) {
        mAuxEffectId = effectId; // <--- just sets a property of the object
    }
    return status;
}

This seems to imply that contrary to the "attach" verb, only a single AuxEffect can be attached to a AudioTrack (meaning a "set" would probably be more appropriate).
Same seems to go for setting the send level. The other calls around the property assignment seem to mostly be to notify about configuration changes, so I'm fairly sure that my statement here is correct.
Also from the docs of setAuxEffectSendLevel they state: "Sets the send level of the audio track to the attached auxiliary effect". This means, you're not setting a volume on the AuxEffect but rather a output volume on the AudioTrack which gets routed to the effect. For me, this also seems to imply that there's no way of differentiating control between multiple AuxEffects further corroborating the assumption only a single AuxEffect is supported.
